# How to display labels and textboxes with the help of model properties in MVC5 razor view with html helpers?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I am not able to create labels and textboxes using model in my view with html helpers.

My View Syntax:

```
  @using (Ajax.BeginForm("RoomsAvail",new AjaxOptions
                                {
                                  UpdateTargetId = "RoomsAvailData",
                                  InsertionMode ="InsertionMode.Replace"
                                }))                                                                                                             
 {
    <input type='text' id="Checkin" class="form-control datepicker" />
    <input type='text' id="Checkout" class="form-control datepicker" />
    <button type="submit" value="Search"></button>
 }
@model IEnumerable<RoomAvailabilitySummary>
 <div>
     @Html.LabelFor(model=>model.ARRDAT)
 </div>
 <div>
     @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
 </div>
```

My Model

```
public class RoomAvailabilitySummary
{
   public string ARRDAT{get;set;}
   public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

After doing like this, my view is not rendering the model properties into my view to display text for labels and getting the error as **"Syste.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable does not contain the definiton for ARRDAT"**

Why i am not able to render model property in my html helper to display the name with the help of html helper?

And also i want to access my model values in controller. How can i do this?

Comment: How could you directly access a field through a list or IEnumerable !

Comment: So, what is the alternate for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your model is:

```
@model IEnumerable<RoomAvailabilitySummary>
```

And you trying to access `Name` in `IEnumerable`:

```
 <div>
     @Html.EditorFor(model=>model.Name)
 </div>
```

You should use `foreach` if it is `IEnumerable` OR just `@model RoomAvailabilitySummary` if it is not `IEnumerable`

**Added:**

Something like this should work:

```
@model IEnumerable<RoomAvailabilitySummary>

@if(Model.Count() > 0)
{
 <div>
     @Html.LabelFor(model=>Model.First().Name)
 </div>
}

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
 <div>
     @Html.EditorFor(model=>item.Name)
 </div>
}
```

Comment: Since, i am displaying the data in the same view from the DB using Entity framework. so, i must use IEnumerable to enumerate my contents. Only problem is not able to display name with the help of model property. Why?

Comment: @Arjun You trying to find `Name` property in `IEnumerable`, not in `RoomAvailabilitySummary` class.

Comment: I am really sorry since i am learing MVC. Please help me how to show both model properties(for html helpers to dislay name etc) and data using the model...that will be really helpful for me.

Comment: @Arjun Look at `Ashok Damani` answer, put your div's in code block and change second `model` to `room`

Comment: But, if i do like this it will show multiple times my item. here, name label i want to show one time with the help of model property and wants to display name multiple times using foreach. How to do that? Hope, i am clear on this. If not, please tell me.

Comment: @Arjun Something like I added?

Comment: I came to know that i confused u and Ashok. My apologies. I have updated my question. Please check it once again. I want to access my model values on HTTPPost method for ajax request to send input parameters(checkin and checkout). Please help me.

Comment: @Arjun If you want submit them, you should put them to your form

Answer (score 0):

I think u are trying to iterate over the model (list):

```
@model IEnumerable<RoomAvailabilitySummary>
@Html.LabelFor(model => model[0].Name)
@foreach(var room in Model)
{
    <br />
    @Html.EditorFor(x => room.Name)
}
```

Comment: Yes Ashok...My intention is i want to display the name for name value which is coming from DB. As you said, i am iterating my DB content using foreach. But, i want to display my model properties too in the same view. Without using IEnumaerate we cant iterate items. So, how to proceed on this?

Comment: Please, change `foreach` to `@foreach` and `model` to `Model`

Comment: name label i want to show one time from model using display property and name value which is coming from db i want to show multiple times based on item count using foreach. How to do this?Hope, i am clear on this Ashok.